# SQL server Computed column giving in-correct result

Tags: sql, calculated-columns

Following SQL Statement returns NULL in MP_SALESID. However if I replace where KRFPRODUCTIONORDERGROUPiD = 'T1.KRFPRODUCTIONORDERGROUPID' with an actual value for T1.KRFPRODUCTIONORDERGROUPID then I am getting a value in MP_SalesId. What am I missing here? I have been fighting this for last 12 hours :(

```
   SELECT T1.KRFPRODUCTIONORDERGROUPID AS KRFPRODUCTIONORDERGROUPID, 
   (CAST ((select top(1) salesId from salesLine 
   join INVENTTRANSORIGIN as SalesLineInventTransOrigin on 
   SalesLineInventTransOrigin.INVENTTRANSID = salesLine.INVENTTRANSID 
   join InventTrans as ProdTableInventTrans on 
   ProdTableInventTrans.MARKINGREFINVENTTRANSORIGIN = 
   SalesLineInventTransOrigin.RECID 
   join INVENTTRANSORIGIN as ProdTableInventTransOrigin on 
   ProdTableInventTransOrigin.recid = 
   ProdTableInventTrans.INVENTTRANSORIGIN 
   join ProdTable on ProdTableInventTransOrigin.INVENTTRANSID = 
   PRODTABLE.INVENTTRANSID 
   where KRFPRODUCTIONORDERGROUPiD = 'T1.KRFPRODUCTIONORDERGROUPID') 
   AS NVARCHAR(20))) AS MP_SALESID
   FROM PRODTABLE T1
```

Comment: Aside from quoting the 'T1.KRFProductionOrderGroupId' in the query, selecting TOP 1 sales ID will just return the FIRST without some context of the order -- based on sales $, number of transactions sold, whatever.  Please EDIT your post and describe what you are TRYING to get out of this.  Ex:  For each product, I am looking for the highest sales associated with ... blah, blah, blah.  Let us have context rather than just fixing a query that might not give you what you THINK it will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use single quote(') around `T1.KRFPRODUCTIONORDERGROUPID`

```
SELECT T1.KRFPRODUCTIONORDERGROUPID AS KRFPRODUCTIONORDERGROUPID, 
   (CAST ((select top(1) salesId from salesLine 
   join INVENTTRANSORIGIN as SalesLineInventTransOrigin on 
   SalesLineInventTransOrigin.INVENTTRANSID = salesLine.INVENTTRANSID 
   join InventTrans as ProdTableInventTrans on 
   ProdTableInventTrans.MARKINGREFINVENTTRANSORIGIN = 
   SalesLineInventTransOrigin.RECID 
   join INVENTTRANSORIGIN as ProdTableInventTransOrigin on 
   ProdTableInventTransOrigin.recid = 
   ProdTableInventTrans.INVENTTRANSORIGIN 
   join ProdTable on ProdTableInventTransOrigin.INVENTTRANSID = 
   PRODTABLE.INVENTTRANSID 
   where KRFPRODUCTIONORDERGROUPiD = T1.KRFPRODUCTIONORDERGROUPID) 
   AS NVARCHAR(20))) AS MP_SALESID
   FROM PRODTABLE T1
```

Comment: *lol* Now I am feeling really dumb, thanks for spotting the mistake.